# How come when I view a website, like Adobe or Godaddy Jolly Wallet pops up?

Tags: malware

Whenever I visit a website like Adobe.com or Godaddy I get a banner like this,

Adobe:
[image: Jolly Wallet on Adobe.com]

Godaddy:
[image: Jolly Wallet on Godaddy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you've installed [**Webpage Screenshot Capture**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot-captur/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en), a popular Chrome extension with malware.

They do say this on the [Extension Download Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot-captur/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en)

> 【Ads】* Webpage Screenshot not inject ads or change content of any site!
>   We are testing new feature. Small amount of the users may see the jollywallet bar on some e-commerce websites. This is not an ad, This is a cash-back platform. You can disable it from the settings page without losing any features as well. Existing users will get notified about this change. More info: http://goo.gl/yWkk3b

Simply uninstall Webpage Screenshot Capture.

This app embeds all kinds of awkward includes when you view these sites and should be viewed as a security concern,

> http://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/jsquery2?dist=197&sub=2&ver=1&aff_ref=0&r=0.09166263858787715